# Chart.Js - Specify x labels to be displayed that is not possible with stepSize option

Tags: chart.js

I need to create a Chart.js that displays by default only the labels 0.1, 0.3 and 0.5 in X axis. In case the value 0.013 needs to be plotted, it should be between 0 and 0.1, but without displaying its specific label. The same for value 0.389, where it needs to be displayed between 0.3 and 0.4, with same behavior.

Currently my graph is displayed like this:
[image]

The desired is something like this:

[image]

Note: even there are no values for some "regions", the labels 0.1, 0.3 and 0.5 should be displayed.

```
config = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [{
            data: [],
            borderWidth: 0,
            borderColor:'#E16972',
            fill: true,
            backgroundColor: "#E16972"
        }]
    },
    options: {
        animation: {
            duration: false, //remove animation
        },
        responsive: true,
        tooltips: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            display: false
        },
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
        elements: {
            point:{
                radius: 0
            }
        },
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                display: true,
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'PSD (Hz/s²)'
                },
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    suggestedMax: 0.2
                }
            }],
            xAxes: [{
                display: false,
            },
            {
                gridLines : {
                    display : false
                },
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: false
                },
                type: 'linear',
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    autoSkip: false,
                    min: 0,
                    max: 0.5,
                    stepSize: 0.1,
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this problem including a callback function.

```
ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    autoSkip: false,
                    min: 0,
                    max: 0.5,
                    stepSize: 0.1,
                    callback: function(label, index, labels) {
                        if(label == 0 || label == 0.1 || label == 0.3 || label == 0.5){
                            return label;
                        }else{
                            return '';
                        }
                    }
                }
```